# Embed a Google Earth Story into an iFrame

Tags: html, google-earth

I have a Google Earth Web Story. (https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/learn/create-a-map-or-story-in-google-earth-web/), and currently, I'm looking to embed it into my website.

I think you see where I'm going with this, as the Google Earth API has been deprecated.

Is there any way to still embed it?
I've looked into alternatives like Cesium but their "Story" features aren't nearly as capable as what Google Earth can provide.

Edit: Looking at Cesium again, it's not bad, it has everything I need, except 3D Maps and Street-view. So I'd still prefer to be able to use Google Earth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, Google Earth does not provide an API nor the ability to embed it in iFrames or web pages.